# Why Python script does not detect import folders when run using C# Process method?

Tags: python, c#, process

I have the following Python script

```
import os
import pathlib

# sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
sys.path.append("utils")
# sys.path.append( '.' )
sys.path.append("./utils")

#from notebook_utils import segmentation_map_to_image, to_rgb
print(f"Python script path : {pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()}")

from notebook_utils import segmentation_map_to_image, to_rgb
```

When I run this at the command prompt, it runs without any issues.

```
Python script path : c:\Users\Rose\Inference
```

When I run the same code using C# Process method, it can not find the folder 'utils'.
C# code :

```
public void runDefectInspection(string imageFolder, string model_path)  //passing image folder
        {
            MessageEventArgs e = new MessageEventArgs();
            e.message = @"<<<<<<< Script initiaited, please wati.... >>>>>>>";
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Process process = new Process();

            start.FileName = g_pythonEXEPath;
            if (File.Exists(g_pythonAlgorythmScript))
            {
                if (File.Exists(start.FileName))
                {
                    string arg = String.Format("--FileName \"{0}\"  --ModelPath \"{1}\"", imageFolder, model_path);

                    start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", g_pythonAlgorythmScript, arg);

                    log.Write("Python file : " + start.FileName + "Python parameters >>> " + start.Arguments);

                    m.message = start.Arguments;
                    sendPythonMessage(this, m);
                    sendPythonMessage(this, e);

                    start.UseShellExecute = false;
                    start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    start.RedirectStandardOutput = !start.UseShellExecute;
                    start.RedirectStandardError = !start.UseShellExecute;

                    process.StartInfo = start;

                    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    process.OutputDataReceived += SJW_Output;
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += SJW_Error;
                    process.Exited += new EventHandler(SJW_Exited);

                    process.Start();

                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
                else
                {
                    m.message = "Python executable not found : " + start.FileName;
                    sendPythonMessage(this, m);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m.message = "Algorythm file not found : " + g_pythonAlgorythmScript;
                sendPythonMessage(this, m);
            }
        }
```

This C# code runs with many other python scripts without any issues when the Python code does not import any other files in different folders in the project. this fails only when calling files in other folders.

The error I get is that it can not find the 'utils' folder.

```
<<<<<<< Script initiaited, please wati.... >>>>>>>
SJW Error :Traceback (most recent call last):
SJW Error :Traceback (most recent call last):
SJW Error :  File "C:\Users\Rose\Inference\sjq_defect_detection.py", line 18, in <module>
SJW Error :    from notebook_utils import segmentation_map_to_image, to_rgb
SJW Error :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook_utils'
SJW Error :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook_utils'
<<<<<<< Script completed >>>>>>>



Folder structure
Inference (Project Folder)
 - sjq_defect_detection.py (running script)
Utils (Folder)
 - notebook_uitls.py (imported in running script)
```

Any help ?